# How to animate triangle vertices in a-frame

Tags: aframe, webvr

I am trying to animate an individual vertex of a triangle primitive in `a-frame` using the animation tag and am having some strange results

In one case, If I try to animate as I would expect to, changing the `x,y,z` values like so...

```
<a-triangle
        vertex-a="-1 1 -5"
        vertex-b="-1 1 -10"
        vertex-c="4 1 -10"
        color="blue"
        material="side: double">
            <a-animation
                attribute="vertex-b"
                from="-1 1 -10"
                to="-1 5 -10"
                dur="4000"
                >
            </a-animation>
    </a-triangle>
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k7fbmo9k/

...I get the following error

> 'THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere(): Computed radius is
>   NaN. The "position" attribute is likely to have NaN values.'

However, If I only offer a single value like so..

```
   <a-triangle
        vertex-a="-1 1 -5"
        vertex-b="-1 1 -10"
        vertex-c="4 1 -10"
        color="blue"
        material="side: double">
            <a-animation
                attribute="vertex-b"
                from="1"
                to="5"
                dur="4000"
                >
            </a-animation>
    </a-triangle>
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k7fbmo9k/1/

..it seems to **'work'** as in no errors and there is animation but I have no control over it.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks for any advice as ever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution. Using the animation component https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-animation-component
the vertices will animate as expected. See example below

```
 <a-triangle
        vertex-a="-1 1 -5"
        vertex-b="-1 1 -10"
        vertex-c="4 1 -10"
        color="blue"
        material="side: double"
        animation="property: vertex-b; to: -1 5 -10; dur: 1000">
    </a-triangle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `attribute="geometry.vertexB"`. It might not work to animate the primitive attributes, so we animate the geometry component directly.

Otherwise, if you are comfortable enough, it is better to animate vertices at a more advanced level for performance. You can use a vertex shader.

Or you can manipulate the vertices manually:

```
var geometry = triangleEl.getObject3D('mesh').geometry;
geometry.attributes.position[0] += 0.1;
geometry.attributes.position[1] += 0.1;
geometry.attributes.position[2] += 0.1;
geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
```

And to animate, do it in a tick handler:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('animate-vertex', {
  tick: function (t) {
    // Animate vertex position until desired position using `t` to interpolate time.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you but that does not work. What does work however (I have just this second discovered) is if I animate it with (your) animation component which is great, thanks. I will add as an answer below

Comment: 'Try' is more something for a comment, also please explain your answer as to how it solves the original problem.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of alternative approaches